# Angularjs | how in directive change classes for siblings of clicked element?

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm quite fresh with Angular, so sorry if my question looks trivial

I have few buttons, I create by ng-repeat. They have some bootstrap classes to make them nice, but if button is "active" gets additional class - active. The problem is only one button can be active, and I have 2 separate groups (containers with different class name) of buttons on page. They should work the same, but clicking on button on one groups should not affect the buttons in other group.

Could you, please help me write a directive, which will bind click event to button and remove 'active' class from all buttons in group and add it to clicked button only?

EDITED:
Here is a code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/996o7nk1/1/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="confApp">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .active {color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ProjectConfCtrl">
        <div class="tans">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-cph" ng-repeat="tan in tans" ng-class="active: tan.active === true" data-tan-type-id="{{tan.id}}">{{tan.name}}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="langs">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-cph" data-ng-repeat="lang in langs">{{ lang.name }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("confApp", []);
app.controller('ProjectConfCtrl', [
  '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tans = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Auto',
            active: true
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Import',
            active: false
        }
    ];
    $scope.langs = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'English',
            active: true
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Spanish',
            active: false
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'German',
            active: false
        }
    ];
  }
]);
```

For fiddle I just changed markup (removed html and head tag and added ng-app to div (it was in html)) but somehow in fiddle it throws an error.

I also added class, but it doesn't work also...

Comment: Even if it doesn't work fully, it would be useful if you could show us the code you've written so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-class together with a variable in the model, like in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L5wm11s2/1/

Notice that I had to put the variables in the controller, not in the scope, and use the `controller as` to be able to access the variables from the view. That's because ng-repeat creates a child scope for each repeated element - a copy of the original scope, but separated from it. Because of that, if I did simply `selectedTan = tan` in ng-click, I'd end up setting the variable in the child scope. That means each button might consider itself selected, because it would have it's own `selectedTan` variable.

Comment: Yay, on fiddle works great, will try to adapt it to my code. Thanks!

Comment: so only one question, how make ng-class work with tan.active ? I have some predefined data (I will take it from api using resource) so I need my HTML see those existing configuration (if any exists)

Comment: Inside the `ng-class` attribute you should put an object where each key is the name of a class. The value of each property of that object will be evaluated and, if it's truthy, angular will add the class to the element; if false, angular will remove the class.
So if the active status of the button depends on `tan.active`, you just need to use `ng-class="{'red-btn':tan.active}"`. But then you'll need to add some extra coda in the controller to guarantee that only one button will be active at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo-Bicalho it works as should. Your explanation made everything much clear for me